# Unable to roll-up total no opportunities at contact custom Field

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a custom field on contact `total_no_of_opp__c` and opp having a lookup of `contact__c` how can i get the total no of opp in contact custom field(`total_no_of_opp__c`).

**Trigger**

```java
trigger RollUp_Opportunity_at_Contact on Opportunity (after insert, after update, after undelete, after delete) 
{
    if(Trigger.isAfter)
    {
    List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
        Set<Id> contactIdsSet = new Set<Id>();
        if(Trigger.isDelete)
        {
  oppList = Trigger.Old;
        }
        else
        {
            oppList = Trigger.New;
        }
        for(Opportunity  opp : oppList)
        {
            if(opp.ContactId != null)
                {
                    contactIdsSet.add(opp.ContactId);
                }
            if(Trigger.isUpdate)
            {
                Opportunity oldOpportunity = (Opportunity)Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id);
                if(oldOpportunity.ContactId != opp.ContactId)
                {
                    contactIdsSet.add(oldOpportunity.ContactId);
                }
            }
        }
   RollUp_Opportunity_at_Contact_Helper.OpportunityCount(contactIdsSet);
    }
}
```

**Helper Class for trigger**

```java
public class RollUp_Opportunity_at_Contact_Helper
{
    public static void OpportunityCount(set<id> abc)
    {
        List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
        List<AggregateResult> agrResult = [Select ContactId, Count(Id) countOpp from Opportunity where ContactId IN : abc Group By ContactId];
        Integer size = agrResult.size();
        for ( Integer i =0; i < size ;  i ++ )  
        {
            AggregateResult agr = agrResult.get(i);
            Id ContactId = (Id)agr.get('ContactId');
            Decimal count = (Decimal)agr.get('countOpp');
            Contact acc = new Contact(Id = ContactId, Total_no_of_Opportunities__c = count);
            conList.add(acc);
            if ( abc.contains( ContactId )) 
            {
                abc.remove(ContactId);
            }
        }
        for ( Id accId : abc ) 
        {
            Contact acc = new Contact(Id = accId, Total_no_of_Opportunities__c = 0 );
            conList.add(acc);
        }
        update conList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Before attempting to code, try using [Declarative Rollup Summary Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/07/a-declarative-rollup-summary-tool-for-force-com-lookup-relationships.html)

Comment: But the requirement is to do using code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have a custom lookup field named `Contact__c`, but your code is using `ContactId`.  This is a standard field, per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm):

> Read-only field that is derived from the opportunity contact role,
> which is created at the same time the opportunity is created. This
> field can only be populated when it’s created, and can’t be updated.

You need to change your code to reference your custom field, not the standard field.

Comment: when I open contact and I want to create a opportunity from that page so how can I get that contact(parent) value automatically populate in opp contact lookup field

Comment: If you have a different question, you should create a new post for it.